# Cauchy integral formula in simple connected domain

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

What are the formulas for:

Cauchy integral formula for **function** in a simply-connected domain

And

Cauchy integral formula for **derivatives** in simply-connected domain.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula (which I would note can be found using the google) is, for $\gamma$ the boundary of a disk in the simply connected domain, and $a$ inside the disk, and $f$ of course holomorphic on the domain, we get
$$
f^{n}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\mathrm dz
$$
If you set $n=0$, you get the formula for the function's value at $a$.